# Using remote library in Eclipse RSE project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2, project

I have a server on debian that I only can access via SSH. So I tried to use RSE on Eclipse and this works fine. I could connect to the server and create files.

The problem is: on Debian, I created the project with Maven. So all the libraries that Maven downloads are on the Debian. In my side, the paths of the libraries are locals... So the path M2_REPO/path/to/the/library is ok on the Debian, but this doesn't exist on my Mac.

For the moment I have manually created the path on my Mac and copied the .jar but this is not really proper. So if you could help me... !